# How to display Bundle Data in Fragment and display it in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to figure out how I would display Bundle data that I have in my fragment and display it in a RecyclerView. In the onClick method of my activity, I get the input from the user and wrap the values in a Bundle. I then send it to the fragment to be displayed in the RecyclerView. I'm a bit stumped on how I would go about setting up my RecyclerView Adapter to display the Bundle data Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my activity code

```
public class OwesActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private Button okButton;
private EditText nameEditText;
private EditText amountEditText;
private Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_owes);

    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    nameEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name_edit_text);
    amountEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.amount_edit_text);

    okButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.okButton);
    okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (isInputEmpty())
            {

            }
                else
                {

                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    extras.putString("nameKey",        nameEditText.getText().toString());
                    extras.putString("amountKey",   amountEditText.getText().toString());

                    Fragment fragment;

                switch (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()) //value of spinner determines which list the extras go to.
                {
                    case 0:// Owes Me
                        fragment = new OwesMeFragment();
                        fragment.setArguments(extras);
                        break;

                    case 1: // I Owe
                        fragment = new OweFragment();
                        fragment.setArguments(extras);
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }

                startNewActivity();

            }
        }
    });

    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.spinner_choices, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public boolean isInputEmpty()
{
    if(nameEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()||
            amountEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Field cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public void startNewActivity()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Here is the Fragment

```
public class OwesMeFragment extends Fragment
{


public OwesMeFragment()
{
    // Required empty public constructor
}




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //Inflate the view for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_owe, container, false);

    Bundle extras = this.getArguments();

    if(extras != null)
    {
        String nameExtra = extras.getString("nameKey");
        String amountExtra = extras.getString("amountKey");


    }

    //get a reference to the recyclerView
    RecyclerView oweRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.owe_recycler_view);

    //set the layoutManager
    oweRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


    return view;

}

  }
```

Lastly here's the adapter(incomplete)

```
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public TextView name;
    public TextView amount;

    public MyViewHolder(View view)
    {
        super(view);
        name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name_title);
        amount = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.amount_title);
    }

}

//Inflate listRow layout
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int ViewType)
{
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.payup_list_row, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position)
{

}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return 0;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are getting data from activity by passing through bundle!

Now do 1 thing Just create One Model class for your data Like ,

```
    /**
     * Created by Uttam on 7/19/2016.
     */
    public class Mydata {
        String nameExtra;

        String amountExtra;

        public Mydata(String nameExtra, String amountExtra) {
            this.nameExtra = nameExtra;
            this.amountExtra = amountExtra;
        }

        public Mydata() {
        }

        public String getAmountExtra() {
            return amountExtra;
        }

        public void setAmountExtra(String amountExtra) {
            this.amountExtra = amountExtra;
        }

        public String getNameExtra() {
            return nameExtra;
        }

        public void setNameExtra(String nameExtra) {
            this.nameExtra = nameExtra;
        }
    }
```

After this, in your Fragment Create List..

```
   List<Mydata> mydataList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now as you are getting data from Bundle so after getting Data

```
Bundle extras = this.getArguments();

if(extras != null)
{
    String nameExtra = extras.getString("nameKey");
    String amountExtra = extras.getString("amountKey");

    //Just add your data in list
    Mydata mydata = new Mydata();  // object of Model Class
    mydata.setAmountExtra(amountExtra );
    mydata.setNameExtra(nameExtra);
    mydataList.add(mydata);

}
```

And at the last now just pass this list to your Adapter by Creating one Setter Method in you Adapte.

```
myAdapter.setMyDataList(mydataList); // passing list to Adapter
```

Before this just Dont forgett to register your Adapter in your fragment!

Create Adapter Like this..

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * Created by Uttam on 7/19/2016.
 */
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Mydata> myDataList;

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        myDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        // Replace with your layout
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.yourLayout_Name, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // Set Your Data here to yout Layout Components..

        // to get Amount 
          myDataList.get(position).getAmountExtra();

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (myDataList.size() != 0) {
            // return Size of List if not empty!
            return myDataList.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void setMyDataList(List<Mydata> myDataList) {
        // getting list from Fragment.
        this.myDataList = myDataList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        // attach you component here using findViewById //
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // itemView.findViewById  
        }
    }
}
```

All set Hope This will help you lot..!

Comment: Thank you! This really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this by simply re-initiate fragment with bundle data in your button's click listener. Though it's not the best way to do this. But it is simplest method.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I'll keep this in mind for next time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the interface method that will called when you click on button and in fragment you can simply implement interface method to rebind adapter.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I'll keep this in mind next time I come across the same problem.